# Windows Event log message field to elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pandas, elasticsearch

I have some event logs that were exported to CSV from powershell. How can I take and expand the message field so I can use the fields inside of it in elasticsearch? I am using pandas at the moment to send data to elasticsearch.

Current method to split is as follows:

```
sec_events['action'] = sec_events.join(sec_events['message'].str.split('\\s\\s\\s\\s', 1, expand=True).apply(pd.Series))[0]
sec_events['message'] = sec_events.join(sec_events['message'].str.split('\\s\\s\\s\\s', 1, expand=True).apply(pd.Series))[1]
```

This outputs my method like:

```
0,mycompname.domm.f.f.a,4688,successaudit,microsoft-windows-security-auditing,3/7/2017 10:38:16 am,3/7/2017 10:38:16 am,NONE,"subject:   security id:  s-1-5-18   account name:  mycompname$   account domain:  domm   logon id:  0x3e7    process information:   new process id:  0x1a54   new process name: c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe   token elevation type: %%1936   creator process id: 0x1b38   process command line:     token elevation type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with user account control policy.    type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  a full token is only used if user account control is disabled or if the user is the built-in administrator account or a service account.    type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  an elevated token is used when user account control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using run as administrator.  an elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the administrators group.    type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.  the limited token is used when user account control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using run as administrator.",a new process has been created.
1,mycompname.domm.f.f.f,4656,failureaudit,microsoft-windows-security-auditing,3/7/2017 10:38:05 am,3/7/2017 10:38:05 am,NONE,subject:   security id:  s-1-5-18   account name:  mycompname$   account domain:  f   logon id:  0x3e7    object:   object server:  security   object type:  key   object name:  \registry\machine\system\controlset001\services\policyagent\parameters\cache   handle id:  0x0    process information:   process id:  0x1b14   process name:  c:\windows\system32\reg.exe    access request information:   transaction id:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}   accesses:  %%4432      %%4435         access reasons:  -   access mask:  0x9   privileges used for access check: -   restricted sid count: 0,a handle to an object was requested.
```

How can I turn the message fields of the windows event logs into fields of elasticsearch/json style format from an exported csv?

I am looking for json format of something like the below so I can ingest into logstash:

```
{message: {
    subject:  ,
    security id: s-1-5-18,
    account name: mycompname$,
    account domain:  domm,
    logon id:  0x3e7,
    process information:  ,
    new process id:  0x1a54,
    new process name: c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe,
    token elevation type: %%1936,
    creator process id: 0x1b38,
    process command line:  ,
    process command line:  ,
    string1: token elevation type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with user account control policy.
             type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.
             a full token is only used if user account control is disabled or if the user is the built-in administrator account or a service account.
             type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.
             an elevated token is used when user account control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using run as administrator.
             an elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the administrators group.
             type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.
             the limited token is used when user account control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using run as administrator.


    action: a new process has been created.

    }
}
```

I have tried a few items like below:

```
sec_events['message'] = sec_events.message.replace([':\s+,', '\[', '\]', ':\s+', ',\s+','\s\s\s'],['":"none","', '{"', '"}', '":"', '","','","'], regex=True)
```

I cant seem to get it working right. Any assistance would be amazing thank you.

I have noticed the following for splits,

```
3 exact white spaces = transition from field to field 
6 exact white spaces = break between the accesses field 
2 exact white spaces = transition from field name to data if the data is there.
```

Comment: Please share sample data, what you have tried including any errors and an example of correctly formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem ended up being the match between matches not picking up the end comma.

Example:

```
,Token elevation type: %%1936,
creator process id: 0x1b38,
process command line:  C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe,
process command line:  ,
```

Matches would only be

```
 Key                    Value
 Token elevation type   %%1936
 process command line   C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```